# Replacement needs a replacement

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

- [replacement](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/replacement)

Questions range from file replacement to find and replace text to hardware replacement

Comment: You're a moderator, so why don't you tag your own question [meta-tag:status-planned]? @OliverSalzburg is not afraid of doing so.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - because mods are supposed to defer to community input before taking action

Comment: I will. Certain obvious cases, we don't wait.

Comment: meh, this is too obvious it will get burninated (and anyone that doesn't agree need to be replaced! >:) :

Comment: [It's dead](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17884929#17884929).